# Guava's ImmutableTable filtering via Java 8 parallel stream

Tags: java, java-8, guava, java-stream, collect

Need help in filtering Guava's ImmutableTable via parallel stream and collector

Immutable tofilterTable;

Usecase : Iterate over toFilter and remove elements which are not present or entry value is false in validEntry table.
     Tradition way of doing it via for loop:

```
  ImmutableTable<MarketplaceArc, String, ObjectB> filterInactive(final ImmutableTable<MarketplaceArc, String, ObjectB> toFilter) {

     final ImmutableTable.Builder filteredResultBuilder =
            ImmutableTable.builder();

     final Map<MarketplaceArc, Map<String, ObjectB>> rowMap = 
     browseMappings.rowMap();

     for (final Map.Entry<MarketplaceArc, Map<String, ObjectB>> 
      rowMapEntry : rowMap.entrySet()) {

        for (final Map.Entry<String, ObjectB> entry : 
           rowMapEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {

           if(ifActive(rowMap.getKey, entry)){
            filteredResultBuilder.put(
                    rowMapEntry.getKey(),
                    entry.getKey(),
                    buildObjectB(entry));
               }
        }
    }
    return filteredResultBuilder.build();
}
```

Is there better and concise way to do this via Java parallelStreams ?

Comment: Fix your question... Your examples look like they don't even went through compilation (`Immutable` is not a Guava type, `ImmutableTable` yes; `ImmutableTable` doesn't take field *names* but object types). We don't work with pseudo code, but with real code. So please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you have and exactly tell us what you expect so that we can help you.

Comment: Fixed it. I was looking for some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do better. You can use `Table.Cell`, for one. This way, you reduce your two loops into one. You can even make your method more generic by using predicates.

I know that you wrote that your app is for Java 8, but it's simply not possible to do so with Java 8 streams and cool stuff like that because `Table` is kind of not really well designed for Java 8, so far (can't build table from an Itera{ble,tor} of `Cell`s; tables don't require `BiPredicate` but `TriPredicate`). So let's improve your code, plain and basic.

**Plain old loop, optimized for `Table`s**

So here's the basic version. Nothing really extraordinary, but does the job in a better way than your way because it doesn't rely on intermediate complex data structures (you keep using maps, for instance, this solution doesn't).

```
ImmutableTable<MarketplaceArc, String, ObjectB> filterInactive(Table<MarketplaceArc, String, ObjectB> unfiltered) {
  ImmutableTable.Builder<MarketplaceArc, String, ObjectB> filtered = ImmutableTable.builder();
  for (Table.Cell<MarketplaceArc, String, ObjectB> cell: unfiltered.cells()) {
    if (isActive(cell.getRow(), cell.getValue())) {
      filtered.put(cell);
    }
  }
  return filtered.build();
}
```

**Generic solution with predicates**

A more generic solution is to have a generic filtering method. Which will make your code more readable, thanks to some Java 8 magic:

```
// Generic method.
<R,C,V> ImmutableTable<R,C,V> filterToImmutable(Table<R,C,V> unfiltered, Predicate<Table.Cell<R,C,V>> predicate) {
  ImmutableTable.Builder<R,C,V> filtered = ImmutableTable.builder();

  // Actually, let's use some Java 8, just because we can!
  unfiltered.cells().parallelStream()
      .filter(predicate)
      .foreach(filtered::put);
  return filtered.build();
}

// Specific predicate
boolean isActiveCell(Table.Cell<MarketplaceArc, String, ObjectB> cell) {
  return isActive(cell.getRow(), cell.getValue());
}

// Use all you've written, with some Java 8, just because we can. Again.
ImmutableTable<MarketplaceArc, Map<String, ObjectB> unfiltered = ... ;
ImmutableTable<MarketplaceArc, Map<String, ObjectB> filtered = filterToImmutable(unfiltered, this::isActiveCell);
```

Comment: hmmm... Looks like I forgot the `buildObjectB` in between. Well, it's rather easy to do so in each of the solutions. I leave that to you since I got distracted by your naming (your method is called `filterXxx` but it also transforms...) Also, for that `buildObjectB`, you can always transform using `Tables.transformValues`.